# my simple C program its a Random Number Geussing game The Probleme Is that The Random Number Is always The same Even With srand(time(NULL))

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

 #include<stdlib.h>

 #include<time.h>



main() {
   int n,counter=0,choice;

   srand(time(NULL));

   n = rand() % 10 + 1;

   printf("Geuss My Number\n");

   while(1){

    counter++;

    scanf("%d" ,&n);

    if(n==choice){

        printf("Correct You Guessed It in %d Tries\n" ,counter);

        break;
    }
    else if (n>choice) printf("Too High\n");

    else printf("Too Low\n");

}
```

}

So, for example, everytime I run the program, the random number is always the same it does not change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant this;

```
scanf("%d" ,&n); -->  scanf("%d" ,&choice);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `scanf` is overwriting your random number `n`.

Change:

```
scanf("%d" ,&n);
```

Into:

```
scanf("%d" ,&choice);
```